# Jboss standalone.bat windows service Wildfly 10

Tags: jboss, wildfly, windows-service, standalone

Olá,

Como eu faço pra criar um windows service pra iniciar automaticamente o standalone.bat?

Comment: Criar uma tarefa agendada ao iniciar o sistema não é mais simples ou tem(ve) algum problema?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$HOME_JBOSS/bin/service install
```

> No Wildfly 10 o diretório `bin\service` foi movido para `docs\contrib\scripts\service`; Apesar de ter sido movido ainda continua funcionando de acordo com a documentação. Nesse caso basta mover/copiar para a pasta bin e rodar `service install`.

Comment: Quando executo o service install
Me dá esse erro:

Using the x86-64bit version of prunsrv
The system cannot find path specified.
ERROR: Failed to load service configuration

Comment: Resolvido! No caso eu só tinha movido o service.bat...
Ao mover todo o conteúdo da pasta 'scripts' para a pasta bin e executar o comando tive o serviço instalado com sucesso.
Obrigado pela ajuda!